# Android studio white screen in preview layout

Tags: android, android-studio

Im noob with this. I can use the emulator, have SVM enabled. I dont know why the preview screen doesnt show anything. I have installed all the SDK TOols.

[White screen Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5QdB.png)

Comment: you should add relevant code in text instead of pictures of it

Comment: In this thread or a. studio ?